# Issue with Spring Transaction Propagation and Optimistic Locking

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, optimistic-locking

I have a setup where an outer method calls an inner method. It is possible that this inner method will throw an exception that will cause it to rollback. I don't want this exception to affect the outer method. To achieve this, I used @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW) on the inner method.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA{
    @Autowired
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void updateParent(Parent parent) {
        update(parent);
        serviceB.updateChild(parent);
    }
}

public class ServiceBImpl implements ServiceB {
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW)
    public void updateChild(Parent parent) {
        checkIfChildHasErrors(parent.getChild()); //throws RuntimeException if Child has errors
        update(parent.getChild());
    }
}

public class Parent {
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    private Child child;

    //insert getters and setters
}

public class Child {
    @Version
    private Integer version;

    //insert getters and setters
}
```

I am still new to Propagation but from my understanding, since the outer method (updateParent) has Propagation.REQUIRED and the inner method (updateChild) has Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW, they are now contained in their own
separate transactions. If inner method encounters an exception, it will rollback but will not cause a rollback on the outer method.

When the outer method runs, it calls the inner method. The outer method is paused while the inner method is being ran. Once the inner method finishes, it is committed since
it is a different transaction. The outer method unpauses. and it is also committed as another transaction.

The issue I am encountering is that the process of committing the outer method is triggering the optimistic locking for the Child class (probably because the value of the version
field was changed after the inner method has ended and was committed). Since the outer method's instance of Child is already outdated, committing it triggers optimistic locking.

My question is:
IS THERE A WAY TO PREVENT THE OUTER METHOD FROM TRIGGERING OPTIMISTIC LOCKING?

I am surprised that the outer method even tries to commit changes to the Child class. I assumed that since the inner method
is contained in its own transaction, the outer method's transaction will no longer include the updateChild method.

I am using Spring 3.0.5 with Hibernate 3.6.10

Comment: One simple solution would be to catch OPTIMISTIC LOCK Exception of inner method from outer method and make it pass the exception.

Comment: Hi Tanjim, it is the outer method that throws the optimistic lock exception. The inner method updates the DB record without exceptions. Also, i don't think its wise to catch and ignore the optimistic lock, I am screwed if a real optimistic lock exception is thrown via concurrent user updates.

Comment: Your propagation is correct. Using Propagation.REQUIRED on outer transaction and Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW on inner transaction will not affect outer transaction for any commit / rollback of inner transaction. Would u please determine that which of your rows are modifying during operation. I think u are working with same row in both transactions for which version field is getting updated and OptimisticLockException is thrown.

Comment: Hi Tanjim, they are definitely updating the same row in the DB

Comment: Then u must get the latest version of row after committing inner transaction and use that version in second transaction for update same row. Otherwise u will get OptimisticLockException.

Comment: update(parent) method is updating parent and serviceB.updateChild(parent) method is updating child. Is Entity Parent and Child are updating same row?? I am getting a little confused here.

Comment: Yes this is confusing to me as well. Why is the outer method trying to update the same row? My guess is because the outer method also calls the inner method, therefore, the transaction of outer method also contains the update for the Child class. Since the inner method is treated as a separate transaction, the inner and outer method's call to update(parent.getChild()) counted as two attempts to update the same record. I don't know if this is normal behavior.

Comment: No this is not possible. As of your code update(parent) is called once from ServiceA and update(parent.getChild) is called once from ServiceA which is a method of ServiceB. There is no possibility to call any of these update methods twice not if Within update method another update is working or parent and child are entities for same table which are updating same row. As u r using child update with a new propagation, it is updating row and increasing version. After that when parent update is going to commit then it find a mismatch in version and throws exception.

Comment: It would be better if u would provide DAO layer codes.

Comment: @poach - What persistence mapping do you have on `private Child child;` in `class Parent`?  I suspect you are cascading the CascadeType.PERSIST operation, in which case you will need to either a) change to not cascade the persist or b) detach the child from the persistenceContext after calling `serviceB.updateChild(parent);` - otherwise JPA will rightly trying to persist the same object twice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using merge for update

For inner transaction

```
Entity entityUpdated = entityManager.merge(entity);
```

For outer transaction

```
if (entityUpdated != null){
    // if inner transaction rolledback entityUpdated will be null. Condition will save u from nullPointerException
    outerEntity.setVersion(entityUpdated.getVersion);
}

entityManager.merge(outerEntity);
```

Comment: Hi Tanjim, merge didn't resolve the issue, unfortunately. I appreciate your help nonetheless.

Comment: Definitely merge is not the point where you are being resolved. Point is when u r updating the row second time just use updated version and its the only way to avoid OptimisticLockingException.